# What's wrong with 'In the beginning the characters are shortly introduced'?

Tags: grammar

Another example sentence for my upcoming exam. There's a mistake somewhere in this sentence. First I thought the mistake was 'shortly', which can't be used with 'introduce'. But then someone pointed out it should be 'AT the beginning'. So which of these is the real mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Why did you think _shortly_ was incorrect here?

Comment: Because *"shortly"* does not usually mean the quality of being short, but the quality of happening a short time from now/then. (On the other hand, the [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shortly?searchDictCode=all) does give *"briefly"* as one possible meaning, so technically that's not a mistake.)

Comment: What Peter said, I thought shortly was only used for time indication, not for the amount of characters in a book, but I could be wrong.

Comment: On the other hand, there is nothing wrong with using *"in the beginning"* rather than *"at the beginning"*. I'd call it an inferior choice of words, but I don't think it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"At the beginning" and "in the beginning" both sound fine to me.  But I'm unclear what "shortly" is doing there.  Normally, it's used like this: "I'll be with you shortly", meaning I'll be with you after a short interval".  So your sentence is saying "In the beginning the characters are introduced after a short interval", which just feels wrong.  You've said that the characters are introduced early in the play/novel/movie, so "shortly" is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree, shortly is completely wrong here. I think it probably means 'briefly'. Of course the other meaning of 'short' is 'curt', ie short to the point of rudeness, but I'm guessing the characters are not rudely introduced!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you intended to say that the characters are _briefly _  introduced.  "Shortly", even though it can be used in idioms like "I'll be with you shortly", would not be appropriate in this place.

Comment: That's what I would replace it with. So the mistake lies in 'shortly', not 'in'?

Comment: Yes. Both "in the beginning" (first words of the King James bible)  and "at the beginning" are correct, with very slightly different shades of meaning.